# Why can I not find a record I know exists within my RSpec test session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

This is my test:

```
  it "should return all relatives of a specific relation - e.g. 'sister'" do
    u1 = create(:user)
    ft = create(:family_tree, user: u1)
    relation = "sister"
    u2 = create(:user)
    ft2 = create(:family_tree, user: u2)
    membership = create(:membership, invited: u2, relation: relation, invited: u1, family_tree: ft)
    expect(u1.relatives(relation).first.user.email).to eq u2.email
  end
```

At the command-line, specifically within the REPL for PRY-Rescue, I can find a successful instance of that `membership` variable that points to a `membership` record:

```
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership
=> #<Membership id: 13, family_tree_id: 106, user_id: 83, created_at: "2015-10-30 00:19:28", updated_at: "2015-10-30 00:19:28", relation: "sister", member_id: 13, connection_sent_at: nil, connection_responded_at: nil, connect_send_limit: nil, connect_times_sent: nil, connected: nil, connect_type: nil, request_status: nil, connection_removed_at: nil, invited_id: 81>
```

However, when I try to find that specific record via `Membership.where...` it returns an empty result.

```
[12] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> Membership.where(user_id: '83')
=> []
[13] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> Membership.where(user_id: 83)
=> []
```

For good measure, I tried the lookup on another attribute `family_tree_id` and I got a similar `nil` result:

```
[14] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> Membership.where(family_tree_id: 106).first
=> nil
```

Despite the fact that the `membership` local variable above shows the existence of both of those records.

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

So after examining the SQL, I think I found the issue.

This is what my `has_many` in my `User` model looks like:

```
has_many :memberships, ->(user){ where("memberships.user_id = :user_id OR memberships.invited_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id) }, dependent: :destroy
```

This is what the SQL that produces looks like:

```
[6] pry(main)> u2.memberships
  Membership Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = $1 AND (memberships.user_id = 3 OR memberships.invited_id = 3)  [["user_id", 3]]
=> []
```

I believe the issue is the first `AND`...which I think stems from the first `has_many :memberships`.

In this case, what should happen is, it searches for a `membership` record with `user_id=3` and finds nothing, but then it should check for `membership.invited_id=3` and it should find something so it should return the membership.

How do I change that first `AND` to an `OR`? Or how do I fix it otherwise, if my solution is not the fix?

**Edit 2**

The purpose of the `membership` model is that, whenever a user gets invited to the family tree of another user...what we do is create a membership for the `invited_user` on the tree of the `inviter_user`. So, basically we are using this `membership` model to manage permissions and access to family trees of different users.

Here are the associations between the models:

```
User 
  has_one :family_tree, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :memberships, ->(user){ where("memberships.user_id = :user_id OR memberships.invited_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id) }, dependent: :destroy

Family Tree
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, dependent: :destroy

Membership
  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :invited, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "invited_id"

Member
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: For clarity, when are you invoking PRY? I imagine it's at the expectation, but please confirm.

Comment: Second, have you checked to see if the transaction had rolled back? You have two problems I can see: Your relatives association may not be working properly, and you might be seeing your DB transactions getting rolled back before you can review them.

Comment: @RichardSeviora I am using the pry-rescue gem - https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-rescue - so it auto-halts whenever an error is hit. So yes, this happens at the expectation. Not sure how to check to see if the transaction rolled back. How do I check that and further debug  that? I suspect you may be right, re: my associations...but I am using this process to help me debug and get there.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to debug these things in console (as opposed to console inside a spec). Here's how to enable SQL logging: http://question.ikende.com/question/2D31343435373938383535

Comment: You can also try running `reload` on the object in memory. If it's been dropped from the DB it'll throw an ActiveRecord exception.

Comment: Just tried `reload` and got this: `[17] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> u1.reload
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID`

Comment: Yep - so it's dropping from the table for some reason. You'll need to look at the SQL logs to figure out when.

Comment: ok...i will resort to console...it is just nice to have Factory Girl create objects for me...rather than doing it manually :(

Comment: Sure is :) But sometimes you need to get down and dirty to figure it out. You probably have multiple problems overlapping, where the dropping records (I think this is a transaction rollback problem) are stopping you from testing your relationship.

Comment: @RichardSeviora - I think I discovered the issue. I updated the question with more debugging results. Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, I think your relationship is a bit funky. The AND is there because it's the integral part of the has many relationship. You can't drop it. It may be helpful if you were to articulate what the membership model is supposed to do, and how it relates between the the person initiating the relationship, and the person receiving it. This way we can figure out what's next.

Comment: @RichardSeviora Ok..I updated the question with more details about what the membership model does and the associations between the other models. Sorry...just updated it again...if you checked the question earlier, refresh it now.

Comment: What's the distinction between User and Member?

Comment: A `User` is a Devise powered user. A member is a temporary representation of an invited user. i.e. say I add you as my brother to my family tree, but we are estranged....you may not want me to get axs to your family tree, but that doesn't change that you are my bro. So a `member` is added to my family tree representing some basic info about my bro. If you accept my invitation, then we escalate the member record/relation into that of a `User` and we form a full connection where both users have axs to both Family Trees.

Answer (score 1):

So I'll answer here now, since SO keeps complaining the conversation is too long.

I think you probably have a number of problems:

The relationship between Users and Members is muddled in the sense that the User and Member serve share roles in certain states. So you're going to have some confusing relationships.

You may want to consider creating a User who represents the credentialed application user, and a Person/GenealogyRecord who represents the person on the family tree. So then I'd login, I'd have an entry for myself on my tree, and then entries for my other family members.

Therefore, you would then replace the membership model with a relationship model that defines the relationship between members of the tree.

So you'd have:

User has many members.
User has one(?) tree, to which he/she attaches members.
Members will have relationships with other members. A simple way to do it would be to establish the father and mother of each member (and inversely, a member's children). A member's siblings will then be the children of their parents.

**Edit 1**

Recognizing that we can't tinker with the fundamentals, you may want to look at having multiple membership relationships for the User. Sent_Memberships, Received_Memberships and the like.

Comment: Hrmm....I understand the logic....but the issue with that is that the app is pretty built out and it mostly works as is. What you suggest would involve a lot of changes in my views, controllers, tests, etc. Right now, I want to focus on just getting these associations to work properly together.

Comment: Gotcha. So I'll quip that the associations are going to be tough to wrangle because the relationship is a bit blurred. I'll edit my answer in a moment.

Comment: Re: your last edit...I get where you are going...and I have other attributes (called `connections`) on my `membership` model that governs the status of the membership (accepted, rejected, removed, active, etc.). All I need right now to be able to do is to easily find all of the memberships on a record where the `user.id` is present in either the `user_id` or `invited_id` field.

Comment: This isn't something that ActiveRecord::Associations handle well. Are you fine with the result being a readonly AR Query? If so, define a method in User that looks like `Membership.where("memberships.user_id = :user_id OR memberships.invited_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id)`.

Comment: Hrmm...ok...I feel you. I will try that.